# Is it posible to refresh a powerpivot table with a macro in a version of excel without powerpivot?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I now that this is more of a license question than a programming question but I couldnt find the answer anywhere.

I have made a powerpivot workbook which I send around amongst colleagues but some of them can't refresh the data and I can't find why. Is it possible that they need a version of excel 2013 which supports powerpivot? Otherwise the workbooks work well for them, i.e. they can use the slicers and trim down the data and look at the graphs an so on.

The macro which refreshes the data is:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("table name").PivotCache.refresh
```

If it is a problem with the macro, can I do the refresh in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

We managed to solve it by changing provider, now colleagues without powerpivot can refresh the data with my macro.

We changed to the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" provider.

You can change the provider under Powerpivot-> Manage-> Existing connections -> Edit -> Advanced and then choose the right provider in the "Providers" dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel 2013 users need to activate the PowerPivot COM add-in in their Excel installations, before they can use the PowerPivot features (including refresh from VBA).

To activate it, go to File -> Options -> Add-ins -> Choose "COM add-ins" from the dropdown and click "Go...", then check the "PowerPivot for Excel"-box.

Comment: Strange, when I tried to check it on and off on my computer, it makes no difference. (I tested in two different workbooks with the same result, it makes no different for my macro but I can of course not manipulate the data when it is off.)